# Why my docker-compose.yml file not finding the package.json file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, docker-compose, package.json

I am trying to dockerize my react/typecsript application, but when I try to docker-compose run frontend it does not find the package.json file. I do not have a DockerFile, only a docker-compose.yml

docker-compose.yml:

```
`version: '3.5'

services:
  frontend:
    image: node:latest
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
    command: bash -c "npm i && npm start"`
```

My root folder is called FULL-STACK-CHALLENGE and structure of my folder as follow:

[Project structure(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkCbY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkCbY.png)

When I try to run the docker-compose.yml file give this error:

```
Creating full-stack-challenge_frontend_run ... done
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-01-12T17_30_41_901Z-debug-0.log
ERROR: 254
```

And I also want to open this application at localhost:3000

Where is the mistake I am making?

I already try to change the name of working_dir or the name of volumes and even try to create a DockerFile and nothing works

Comment: because your package.json file is down in the exchange-currencies directory. Either change your working_dir to /app/exchange-currencies or move the package.json file up a directory level.

Comment: You can consider debugging step by step. Starting by printing files in the container's main directory: `command: ls`